# Run Flutter Mobile App using AWS EC2 Mac Instance: Flutter

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, flutter, macos, amazon-ec2

I want to run a **Flutter Mobile App on IOS** but **do not have access to MAC**. Is it possible to run my app on IOS/Mac using **AWS EC2 Mac Instance**? If it is possible what steps do I need to follow? If not, is there any other way to run the app without MAC? I have a good knowledge of Flutter and Mobile App Development but am new to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

The trending solution is [Codemagic](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-build-and-distribute-ios-apps-without-mac-with-flutter-codemagic/), but if the EC2 Mac Instance allows you to run XCode/Simulator then it should be fine to test or release your app.

Alternative popular solution could be using virtual mac machine in your system.